# each helper doesn't display firebase data

Tags: ember.js, firebase

app/template/post.hbs:

```
<div>
  {{input type="text" value=newTitle class="form-control" placeholder="Enter title" autofocus="autofocus"}}
  {{input type="text" value=newBody class="form-control" placeholder="Enter text" autofocus="autofocus"}}

  <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" {{action 'saveBlogPost'}}>Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  {{#each post in model}}
    <div>
      <div>{{post.title}}</div>
      <div>{{post.body}}</div>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

app/models/post.js:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  body: DS.attr('string')
});
```

app/routes/post.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    //tried without without .then and without reload: true. no luck.
    return this.store.findAll('post', {reload: true}).then( function(result) {
      return result;
    });
  }
});
```

app/controllers/post.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  newTitle: '',
  newBody: '',
  actions: {
    saveBlogPost() {
      const newPost = this.store.createRecord('post', {
        title: this.get('newTitle'),
        body: this.get('newBody')
      });
      newPost.save();
    }
  }
});
```

In ember inspector, there are 8 `post` model entries in firebase. However, when I go to `http://localhost:4200/posts`, only the top divider appears and not the bottom one (with `#each` helper). What am I doing wrong? I can actually store data with the text fields and button on the top divider.

```
C:\project-path>ember -v
version: 2.4.2
node: 4.4.0
os: win32 ia32
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Ember 2.x, it's `{{#each model as |post|}}`. See the [relevant deprecation](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_more-consistent-handlebars-scope).

You should be getting an error about that syntax, if I remember correctly.